# Values are not updating in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have one table , in that i have `4 text fields`. So when i enter the values in all text field box. And when i press `Update button`. The entered values are not showing in my database. Here is my code :

**This below code is for textfield box:**

```
<td class="answer">
<input type="text" name="Answer1" value='<?php echo $obj["Answer1"]; ?>' /></td>

<td class="answer">
<input type="text" name="Answer2" value='<?php echo $obj["Answer2"]; ?>' /></td>

<td class="answer">
<input type="text" name="Answer3" value='<?php echo $obj["Answer3"]; ?>' /></td>

<td class="answer">
<input type="text" name="Answer4" value='<?php echo $obj["Answer4"]; ?>' /></td>
```

**My update button code :**

```
if(isset($_POST["update_question"]))
  {
      $Question_Id=$_POST["update_question"];
      $Question_Name=$_POST["Question_Name"];
      $Answer1=$_POST["Answer1"];
      $Answer2=$_POST["Answer2"];
      $Answer3=$_POST["Answer3"];
      $Answer3=$_POST["Answer4"];

      $update_question="UPDATE `tblquestions` SET `Question_Name`='".$Question_Name."', `Answer1`='".$Answer1."', `Answer2`='".$Answer2."', `Answer3`='".$Answer3."', `Answer4`='".$Answer4."',`ModifiedDate`=NOW()   WHERE `Question_Id`='".$Question_Id."'";
      $update_result=mysqli_query($con,$update_question);
      if($update_result)
      {
        echo "<script> window.location.href='question.php?msg=sucmsg';</script>";
      }
      else
      {
        echo "<script> window.location.href='question.php?msg=errmsg';</script>";
      }

  }


<button type="submit" name="update_question" class="button" value="<?php echo $obj["update_question"]; ?>">Update</button>
```

When i enter all the field value , and when i press nothing update in my database.Thanks in advance !

Comment: Is the question_id set? Print out the statement and check it

Comment: What is the data type of the column Question_Id ?

Comment: Learn about prepared statements to prevent SQL-injection

Comment: Where do you set `$obj`?

Comment: @Jens no its not printing the value

Comment: @Bharath So add the id to your form

Comment: @Barmar Here : $obj=mysqli_fetch_array($qry);

Comment: why are you echoing javascripts that changes location.href instead of setting the location header in PHP. Why are you not adding echo statements all over the place to see which code gets excecuted and which does not?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$obj['Question_Id']`?

Comment: @Jens  Like this : `$Question_Id=$_POST["update_question"];
       echo '<script>alert("' . $Question_Id . '")</script>';` i am new to php. Let me know any other.

Comment: @Bharath as hidden filed in your html page

Comment: @Barmar Yeah i did like that only.

Comment: @Jens No hidden field

Comment: @Bharath You have to add it

Answer (score 1):

You miss these fields in the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Question_Id" value='<?php echo $obj["Question_Id"]; ?>' /></td>
//just to set any value inside to update_question:
<input type="hidden" name="update_question" value='1' /></td>
```

Change also the button this way:

```
<input type="submit" class="button">Update</input>
```

Then in the script:

```
if(isset($_POST["update_question"]))
  {
      $Question_Id=$_POST["Question_Id"];
...

}
```

Answer (score -1):

There's no `update_question` column in your table, that's the name of the submit button. The column name is `Question_Id`, so you should use `$obj['Question_Id']` instead of `$obj['update_question']`.

Comment: i did like that only but still its not updating. `<button type="submit" name="update_question" class="button" value="<?php echo $obj["Question_Id"]; ?>">Update</button>`

Comment: If you use `View Source`, do you see the correct ID in the value attribute?